# Using pd.concat to add null valued columns from list if not in dataframe?

Tags: dataframe

I got the below performance warning

> PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented. This is usually the result of calling frame.insert many times, which has poor performance. Consider using pd.concat instead. To get a de-fragmented frame, use newframe = frame.copy()

when I tried to add columns to a dataframe from a list.

The warning asks me to consider using pd.concat. But it looks like pd.concat does not take lists.

I am trying to create a set of dataframes from Excel with the same columns and rows. Each file I'm working with has a slightly different set of numbered columns. I tried iterating over a list to add the columns that are missing.

But since that throws a performance warning, I'd like to improve performance. A sample of my code is below.

```
missing_columns = list(map(str, [*range(1900, 2022, 1)]))

for f in files:
    data = pd.read_excel(f)
    cols = data.columns.values.tolist()
    new_cols[0] = 'Company'
    data.columns = new_cols
    for missed in missing_columns :
        if missed not in new_cols:
            data[missed] = np.NAN
    data = data.set_index('Company')
    data = data.reindex(sorted(data.columns), axis = 1)
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am trying to process a set of Excel files that have different sets of columns, and I want to add any missing columns to the dataframes so that they all have the same set of columns.

One issue with my code was that it used a for loop to iterate over the missing cols list and add missing columns to the dataframes. This approach can be inefficient because it requires the code to iterate over the entire missing cols list for each dataframe, which can take a long time if the list is large and the dataframes are large.

One way to improve the efficiency of the code is to use the reindex method to add missing columns to the dataframes, rather than using a for loop. The reindex method can add missing columns to a dataframe and fill them with a specified value, such as NaN, which is what I tried in the for loop. By using the reindex method, I can avoid the need to iterate over the years list and add missing columns one at a time, which can improve the performance of the code.

Here how I used the reindex method to add missing columns to the dataframes:

```
# Get the complete set of columns for the dataframes
all_columns = ['Company'] + missing_columns

# Reindex the dataframes to include all columns
data = data.reindex(columns = all_columns, fill_value = np.NAN)
```